# How to select a directory (dialog) and print selected direcorty on the GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I create a small gui with a browse button where the user has to click to open the directory choose dialog.
After the user selected a directory I want to display the selected path on the gui as a simple text.

How do I do it?
If I put the

```
txt_path = tk.Label(master=root,textvariable=path)
txt_path.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

in the browse_button function there appears no text with the selected directory, only the print will work.

If I put

```
txt_path = tk.Label(master=root,textvariable=path)
txt_path.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

outside of the browse_button function then an error appears:

> txt_path = tk.Label(master=root,textvariable=path) NameError: name
>   'path' is not defined

because the path variable is not defined yet- is the correct way to make the path variable global?
My code:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

def browse_button():
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if len(path) > 0:
        print('OK: ' + path)
        # txt_path = tk.Label(master=root,textvariable=path)
        # txt_path.grid(row=1, column=0)
    else:
        print('ERROR')


###########################################################
#  GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("650x400")

btn_Browse = tk.Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button)
btn_Browse.grid(row=0, column=0)
txt_path = tk.Label(master=root,textvariable=path)
txt_path.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a global variable. The problem is that you're trying to define the label's text as a variable that might stay undefined because it's first defined out of the main function. I fixed your code:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk


def browse_button():
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if len(path) > 0:
        print('OK: ' + path)
        txt_path = tk.Label(master=root, text=path)
        txt_path.grid(row=1, column=0)
    else:
        print('ERROR')


###########################################################
#  GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("650x400")

btn_Browse = tk.Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button)
btn_Browse.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I wrote the lines you put with comment again, with a little changee - I changed the attribute `textvariable` to `text` of the `txt_path` label.